# Assigning values from Firestore to variables in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been pulling my hair out for hours during the switch from Real-time Database to Firestore, I'm trying to figure out a way to assign fields from multiple documents (each document contains a photo and a caption) for display in-app, my code as of now looks like a 3-year-old just threw a tantrum on the keyboard but any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I've been through the documentation hundreds of times, and read basically all similar questions here on StackOverflow but nothings working.

P.S. I've not slept in over 36 hours over this.

```
        db.collection("posts").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        // get the data of all the documents into an array
        var data = querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
            return documentSnapshot.data();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simplified version of what you are trying to do. Once you have your data in hand, you can unwrap them individually, like in the example below, or map them to custom Swift objects. But it appears that your question is only about getting data from Firestore.

```
featuredAttractionsQuery.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else { // unable to get snapshot
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        return // terminate query
    }
    guard !snapshot.isEmpty else { // snapshot is empty
        print("snapshot is empty")
        return // terminate query
    }
    for doc in snapshot.documents { // iterate through documents
        guard let caption = doc.get("caption") as? String,
            let imagePath = doc.get("imagePath") as? String else {
                continue // if we can't get these two values,
                         // move to next iteration and continue loop
                         // calling return here would exit the function
        }
        // do something with this document's data
        // most likely you'll parse it into a native object
        // and add it to an array
    }

    // the loop is complete, reload the table view or collection view
}
```

There is a lot more that goes into this, such as using dispatch queues to parse your data in the background and dispatch groups to handle image downloads which return asynchronously. But this is the basic starting point that virtually all parsing is founded on.

Comment: Thank you! you've solved the issue for me, I've been bashing my head off the keyboard for hours over this one :)

Comment: Stop bashing your head and start posting here instead 

Comment: @user1968625 This is a Super good answer; it protects the code and is correct. An issue to consider is that if a node doesn't contain the *caption* key, then the node is not read in. There's also a mix of `guard` and `let` statements. An alternate option is to use nil coalescing to protect the code and set default values when a key is not found. That way the code is protected and if some of the data exists it's still retrieved. So vars would be assigned like this `let caption = doc.get("caption") as? String ?? "No Caption"` and `let imagePath = doc.get("imagePath") as? String ?? "No Path"